# How to launch android app in advanced or user mode; app reads variable on launch

Tags: android, environment-variables, launch

Sorry this will be a general question as I don't even know where to start.
What I want:
I have an app on androind (bonus if solution works on iOS) where the same app can present different views depending on if you are an end user or a technician. What I need is some SIMPLE method where the app at launch can read a variable. I have read a lot about shortcuts, Quick action, Environment variables, etc. etc. but I can't find anything that doesn't require as much programming as the app itself!
I can think of two approaches…

- long press on Icon which gives the option to start in "advanced mode" by passing an argument to the app
- some setting that can be read by the app at launch akin to an Environment variable in other OS
  Can someone please send my in the right direction. Maybe there is a standard way of doing this I'm just not aware of?
  Many thanks!

Comment: How would this variable be set?

Answer (score 0):

You could present the user with a dialog on first start. He can indicate his "role" either by choosing one, or by entering a password or enabling code.

Or, you can default the app behaviour to "user", and offer a menu option to "enable technician mode", which could then request a password or other code to enable this option.

Or, you can default the app behaviour to "user" and if the user performs a specific magic gesture (ie: swipe right, swipe left, swipe right) then the "technician" mode is enabled.

Comment: All your suggestions are valid solutions. What I was hoping for is closest o the last where app starts by default in user mode. The problem I'm facing is that the app needs to start with different behavior which I was hoping a user would not see. So ideally I would have the app read a variable at launch. The start is complicated, the app connects to BLE and does a bunch of other things. If you're a user some stuff will be hidden. In Linux I would just do e.g. app --tech, but lacking arguments on an Android phone I'm looking for some way to replicate that.

Comment: I still do not understand how this variable would be set on some devices and not set on others. You could, for example, create a second app. Technicians would install the second app as well. Just the presence of the second app could alter the behaviour of the first app. My question is still: how would the variable be set for the technician?

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to do is apparently not possible, so instead I worked around it by always starting the app in user mode and having a hidden button for techs. Of course a user could find it by mistake but if security becomes an issue I will have to add a tech login. For now this solution is acceptable.
It did require some rework to get the sequence right but it turned out to be the lesser evil.